как таковой (agreement)
From РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Тому и другому чуждо представленіе о трагическомъ въ жизни, какъ
таковой; оба съ одинаковой рѣшительностью отрекаются отъ стараго міра,
хотя міръ одного — не міръ другого; одинъ и другой имѣютъ каждый свою
обѣтованную землю, которая течётъ млекомъ и мёдомъ.

Is there a good reason why таковой does not agree? Why isn't it: о трагическом в жизни, как о таковом? Why is таковой nominative?

It agrees with жизни which is feminine locative.

That didn't occur to me! It seemed to me obvious that "the tragic" was what was being referred to. I've got it now.
